# Как прикрутить opengl к окну создаваемым конструктором форм в среде visual prolog

Tags: c++, opengl

```
#include <windows.h>

#include "Windows.h"


#include <memory.h>

#include "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/GL/gl.h"
#include"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/GL/glu.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"C:/lib/opengl32.lib")



_declspec(dllexport)void initOpengl(

    int colorBits, int depthBits,
    float a,float b,float c,float d



    )
{


    HGLRC hrc;


    GLuint pixelFormat;
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, NULL);
    HWND hwnd = GetNextWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDPREV);


    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = 
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |  
    PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |    
    PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
    pfd.iPixelType =PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = colorBits;
    pfd.cRedBits = 0;
    pfd.cRedShift = 0;
    pfd.cGreenBits = 0;
    pfd.cGreenShift = 0;
    pfd.cBlueBits = 0;
    pfd.cBlueShift = 0;
    pfd.cAlphaBits = 0;
    pfd.cAlphaShift = 0;
    pfd.cAccumBits = 0;
    pfd.cAccumRedBits = 0;
    pfd.cAccumGreenBits = 0;
    pfd.cAccumBlueBits = 0;
    pfd.cAccumAlphaBits = 0;
    pfd.cDepthBits = depthBits;
    pfd.cStencilBits = 0;
    pfd.cAuxBuffers = 0;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    pfd.bReserved = 0;
    pfd.dwLayerMask = 0;
    pfd.dwVisibleMask = 0;
    pfd.dwDamageMask = 0;

    if (false(pfd)){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет pixelformatdescriptor", L"нет pixelformatdescriptor", MB_OK); }





    HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);


    //if (!(GetDC(hwnd))){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет GetDC(hWnd)", L"нет GetDC(hWnd)", MB_OK); }
    //if (!hdc){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет hdc", L"нет hdc", MB_OK); }
    //if (hdc){ MessageBox(hWnd, L"есть hdc", L"есть hdc", MB_OK); }
     //   MessageBox(hwnd, L"проверка", L"проверка", MB_OK);
    pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd);

    if (!(ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd))){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd)", L"нет ChoosePixelFormat(hdc, &pfd)", MB_OK); }
    SetPixelFormat(hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd);
    //if (!(SetPixelFormat(hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd))){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет SetPixelFormat(hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd)", L"нет SetPixelFormat(hdc, pixelFormat, &pfd)", MB_OK); }
    hrc = wglCreateContext(hdc);
    //if (!(wglCreateContext(hdc))){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет wglCreateContext(hdc)", L"нет wglCreateContext(hdc)", MB_OK); }
    wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc);
    if (!(wglMakeCurrent(hdc, hrc))){ MessageBox(hwnd, L"нет wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc)", L"нет wglMakeCurrent(hdc,hrc)", MB_OK); }
    //UpdateWindow(hwnd);


        glClearColor(a, b, c, d);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        SwapBuffers(hdc);

    }
}
```

Вместо окна закрашивается весь экран,по книгам вроде как должно работать, функция `MessageBox` работает нормально,выводит сообщения.

Comment: это домашнее задание? если нет то если вам из C++ кода доступен заголовок windows.h я бы посмотрел в сторону создания нативного окна виндовс для работы с opengl

Answer (score 1):

1. Папка `.../VC/include` по умолчанию уже включена в список поиска, а потому указывать полные пути до заголовочных файлов OpenGL необязательно:

   ```
   #include <GL/gl.h>
   #include <GL/glu.h>
   ```
2. Вы как-то странно ищете нужное окно:

   ```
   HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL, NULL);
   HWND hwnd = GetNextWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDPREV);
   ```

   Первый вызов возвращает описатель окна рабочего стола, которое как раз и растянуто на весь экран. Надо делать следующим образом:

   ```
   HWND hwnd = имяОкна->GetSafeHwnd();
   ```
3. Библиотечные файлы крайне желательно включать не через директиву `pragma`, а через свойства проекта (<kbd>Configuration properties → Linker → Input → Additional Dependencies</kbd>). И да, разве OpenGL-ные библиотеки уже не подключены по умолчанию?